# Quotes not closing file path?

Tags: powershell

My program installs parts of SQL Server. This line of code calls the setup exe file. Right now it seems like it's tripping up on the space in the file path.

Here's my code:

```
cmd /c "\\dcsrv1\Software\SQL 2014 Installs\SQL 2014 Unpacked\setup.exe" /configurationfile="\\dcsrv1\Software\SQL 2014 Installs\SQL 2014 Unpacked\Tools\Tools_Original.ini" /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS
```

And here's the error:

```
'\\dcsrv1\Software\SQL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I tried putting the file path in single and double quotes, both with the same results. I saw another question on stackoverflow that said to try an '&' before the path, but I just got a syntax error with that.

One thing that does work is if I have the install files locally (instead of on a server like they are now), and I do cd to the directory and then `cmd /c setup.exe`. Unfortunately I have to do this with network files, I just thought this was interesting.

Is there a way to change directory to a network directory? As far as I've seen it's not really possible.

Comment: With PowerShell 5.0, I have no trouble using `cd \\servername\sharename` to change directory to a network share. Also, for something cleaner, try PSDrives: `New-PSDrive -Name X -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\servername\sharename`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to use echo args to see what args get passed to the command line. see https://chocolatey.org/packages/echoargs

```
echoargs "\\dcsrv1\Software\SQL 2014 Installs\SQL 2014 Unpacked\setup.exe" /configurationfile="\\dcsrv1\Software\SQL 2014 Installs\SQL 2014 Unpacked\Tools\Tools_Original.ini" /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS
```

Is this what you would expect?

```
PS > echoargs "\\dcsrv1\Software\SQL 2014 Installs\SQL 2014 Unpacked\setup.exe" /configurationfile="\\dcsrv1\Software\SQL 2014 Installs\SQL 2014 Unpacked\Tools\Tools_Original.ini" /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS
Arg 0 is <\\dcsrv1\Software\SQL 2014 Installs\SQL 2014 Unpacked\setup.exe>
Arg 1 is </configurationfile=\\dcsrv1\Software\SQL 2014 Installs\SQL 2014 Unpacked\Tools\Tools_Original.ini>
Arg 2 is </IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS>
```

I don't know if you would have better luck with the call operator rather than shelling to cmd, I typically do. Good luck...

```
& "\\dcsrv1\Software\SQL 2014 Installs\SQL 2014 Unpacked\setup.exe" /configurationfile="\\dcsrv1\Software\SQL 2014 Installs\SQL 2014 Unpacked\Tools\Tools_Original.ini" /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS
```

Comment: I didn't know the syntax was that simple for using '&'. It's working now using the call operator. Thanks!